# doubly linked list in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I wanted to do a double linked list in Nasm .

I have this structure for Node

```
struc node
left:   resd    0
right:  resd    0
data:   resd    0
endstruc
```

I do this when i want to use malloc

```
push    dword   [node_sz]   
call    [malloc]
add     esp,    4 * 1
```

Where:

```
node_sz dd 4*3
```

Now i have in eax a pointer (offset) to the new location . Where are locations for my structure Node camp ( left , right ,data  ). For example i want to create a root with no neighbours with value 6. How i do that ?

```
mov [eax + data] , DWORD 6 
mov [eax +left],DWORD 0
mov [eax+right],DWORD 0
```

or maybe

```
mov [eax + 4*2] , DWORD 6 
mov [eax +4*0],DWORD 0
mov [eax+4*1],DWORD 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You forgot the dots at the beginning of each structure member. Also, the value after `resd` is the number of data items to "reserve" in the structure. It should be 1 in this case, not 0.

```
;; Declare a structure called "node".
;; Its size is an EQU named "node_size".
struc node
  .left:   resd    1
  .right:  resd    1
  .data:   resd    1
endstruc

;; External functions we wish to link against
extern malloc

start:
    push    node_size    ;; Use this constant instead of manually calculating
    call    malloc
    add     esp, 4

    mov [eax + node.left],  DWORD 6
    mov [eax + node.right], DWORD 7
    mov [eax + node.data],  DWORD 0xDEADBEEF
```

Example:

```
$ nasm -f elf struc.s

$ objdump -Mintel -d struc.o 

struc.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <start>:
   0:   6a 0c                   push   0xc
   2:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   3 <start+0x3>
   7:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
   a:   c7 00 06 00 00 00       mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x6
  10:   c7 40 04 07 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x4],0x7
  17:   c7 40 08 ef be ad de    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x8],0xdeadbeef
```

Comment: something is not ok with this because when i do `mov [eax + node.left], DWORD 6 `  and than  `mov [eax + node.data]` i'am overwriting at the same offset , node.left and node.data are equals with 0

Comment: @user3052078 I fixed it. You had `.left: resd 0`, which means "reserve 0 `DWORDS`".  Changing it to `1` works as expected. See my example which includes disassembly.